# unresolved external symbol with including glfw3 from inside a library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, glfw

I have a project that includes the GLFW3 library, and a second project that includes the first project as a lib file, but when I compile the second one I get this error:

```
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSwapBuffers
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwTerminate
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetMouseButtonCallback
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwPollEvents
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwInit
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetKeyCallback
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetWindowShouldClose
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwCreateWindow
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetInputMode
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwMakeContextCurrent
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwDestroyWindow
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetCursorPosCallback
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwSetWindowSizeCallback
1>Duno-Core.lib(Display.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_glfwWindowShouldClose
```

I've been trying to figure out why this is happening and cannot find anything like this, anywhere. If you can figure out all the horrible mistakes I’ve made, then that will help me massively!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean _project includes_? The library must be linked against your final executable program.

Comment: Do you link statically? Then you need to link with the full dependency tree.

Comment: What I mean by include is link staticly with '.lib' files

Comment: @thegamingmoose Did you figure this out? I am facing the same problem.